# Dynamo: Can I draw a system family into revit by programing in Dynamo?

Tags: pipe, revit

We can use FamilyInstance to call out and insert the custom family into the revit project. However, it doesn't work for system family. For example: How can I draw a pipe using dynamo? Which one is the suitable node for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Revit API provides the Pipe.Create method to place new pipe elements, which are system family instances, just as you say:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/01/final-rolling-offset-using-pipecreate.html

Yes, you can certainly call this method from Python and Dynamo as well, just like the NewFamilyInstance method.